# how i can prevent css and js files from routing with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I am trying to redirect all user requests to a bootstrap file, but when I do that the `CSS` and other files redirected.

How I can prevent this?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^.*]+$) index.php?URL=$1 [TR,L]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can preface your rewrite rule with the following two lines to check if a file/directory exists before rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ...
```

If you want to whitelist only certain files/folders, you can exclude them in the rule itself:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!css|js|images|testfile\.php) ...
```

Comment: Not Worked!Can You Write Full Code?Thanks